# Importing System.Net.Mail in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, email

I have added Global.asax file to my website.  I need to send email through that.  Everything is fine but I do not know how to Import System.Net.Mail to the file.

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I still wanted to respond for others who stumble upon this.  If you are developing a WSP (Web Site Project) as opposed to a WAP (Web Application Project), your Global.asax file will be one file and not split into two.  If you are trying to access a namespace, simply use this:  `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>` right above the `<script runat="server">`.

Answer (score 1):

If your global.asax has a code behind, simply put this in the code behind

VB

```
Import System.Net.Mail
```

C#

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

If you do not have a code behind, then put it in a script block.

```
<script runat="server">
Import System.Net.Mail //VB
using System.Net.Mail; //C#
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
Import System.Net.Mail
```

to the head of your global.asax codebehind file (global.asax.vb, if you are using VB).

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.  I am trying it at the top of the file, where it begins but it does not accept it.

Comment: @FurqanSehgal: "Does not accept it" is not a very helpful error description. If you get an error message, please tell us what it says!

Answer (score -1):

The answer is, you just put it at the top